# How to run jscodeshift transform on all files?

Tags: jscodeshift

I am creating a transform that will replace all instances of:

```
templateUrl: 'some/url/to/some.html'
```

with

```
template: require('some/url/to/some.html')
```

I am doing this because I am changing the way that our AngularJS code brings in their templates. I am going to make them all use the webpack string loader.

I have gotten the transform to work. But now I have no idea how to run it against all of the files in my project. I can't see in the documentation how to run this against all of the `.js` files in my project. To run my transform, I currently type:

```
jscodeshift ./folder/myComponent.js -t ./tools/codemodes/template.js -d -p
```

This command will run my transform against the `myComponent.js` file, but I want it to be run against all of the `.js` files in my project. What do I need to change with my current command to make it select all `.js` files, and run the transform against all of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to run a transform against all files in a directory, you just enter the directory path, instead of a file path. In the example above, do the following:

```
jscodeshift ./folder -t ./tools/codemod/templates.js -d -p
```

That will run the transform against all of your nested js files.

Answer (score 4):

The answer provided by frosty will run on all files in the directory, not just JS files. If you want to just run the transform on all nested JS files, use the `**` glob syntax:

```
jscodeshift ./path/to/folder/**/*.js -t ./tools/codemod/templates.js -d -p
```

Note that certain shells don't recognize `**` and you will have to first manually turn it on with:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
```